# Can't bind to ':xlink:href' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:image'

Tags: angular, svg

I am trying to set dynamicly href for svg image like this :

```
<svg style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <image x="-29" y="7" height="53" width="170" xlink:href="{{logoFile}}"  />
</svg>
```

but then I got error in console :
Can't bind to ':xlink:href' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:image

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Since `xlink:href` is an attribute but not a property of the SVG [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGImageElement) element, use [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding):

```
[attr.xlink:href]="logoFile"
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-xqclef) for a demo.

Comment: How can I do for loop of hrefs like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pq6r2w. I've asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733093/how-to-update-svg-image-href-dynamically-in-angular-html/58733809#58733809