# How to update SVG Image href dynamically in angular html?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, svg, css-animations

*I'm looping through list of employee objects in which each object has imageUrl and I need to use that image url in the svg - Image*

```
<div *ngFor ="emp of employees">
        <defs>
         <pattern id = "attachedImage" height = "100%" width = "100%" patternContentUnits = "objectBoundingBox">
            <image href="{{emp.ImageUrl}}"  preserveAspectRatio = "none" width = "1" height = "1"/>
        </pattern>
        </defs>
        <circle cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "35%" fill = "url(#attachedImage)"/>
    </div>
```

I don't want to loop through all the html elements  in JS. Even if I do, I want to map the appropriate image

Is there any way I can dynamically append that Url in this image
I tried using {{emp.ImageUrl}} which didn't work.

This is the URL of working example where I've hardcoded the URL
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pq6r2w

I want to add the URL dynamically

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Put it in stackblitz

Comment: @dota2pro I've updated with stackblitz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your markup is that you reuse the same `id` for all pattern images. As a result, the first image is shown in all the shapes. You can use the `ngFor` loop index to make each `id` distinct:

```
<div *ngFor="let emp of employees; let i = index">
  ...
  <svg class="circle-chart" ...>
    ...
    <g class="circle-chart__info">
      <defs>
        <pattern [id]="'attachedImage_' + i" ... >
          <image [attr.xlink:href]="emp.ImageUrl" ... />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <circle [attr.fill]="'url(#attachedImage_' + i + ')'" ... />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can see the result in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1fzlmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Please note that I also set the `https` protocol on the second image to make it visible in the view.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey can you please check this! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58742040/how-to-add-fallback-image-if-the-image-is-broken-in-svg-inline

Comment: I'd like to add that when binding the href attribute on an image, don't use an XSS escaped URL. It will tell you to use property binding, which you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is the right solution but it works for me.

You can try it like this:

```
[src]=emp.ImageUrl
```